# Another intuitive proof of Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics

if one prove that the distribution of the sample mean is symmetrical, and prove that its mean is the mean of the original population and it's variance is $\frac{\sigma^{2}}{N}$, is it possible to prove the CLT arguing that the only PDF with these properties has a normal distribution ?

Comment: Well, that's not true, so...

Comment: I'm sorry i edited

Comment: That's still not true. There are many distributions with those properties.

Comment: And if i also prove that is monotonic on the left and right sides of the mean ?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, no that's not enough.  Furthermore, the sample mean need not be symmetrical if the underlying distribution of the samples isn't.  However, you *are* coming close to another way of proving the central limit theorem: it's not enough to just show that the sample mean has the correct mean and variance; however, if you show that all moments of the (recentered and renormalized) sample mean converge to the moments of the standard normal, then you get a proof of the central limit theorem.  This is known as the moment method or the method of moments, although "the method of moments" also refers to a different concept in statistics.  For a proof of the CLT using the moment method, see [this blog post by Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/254a-notes-2-the-central-limit-theorem/).

Comment: However it seems not an intuitive proof :(

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for; there are a lot of proofs of the central limit theorem, but it's hard to say if any are intuitive.  One that's somewhat intuitive but quite difficult to carry out a proof of is by noting that the entropy of the sample means increases with $n$, and that the standard normal maximizes entropy.  [Here's a thread on MathOverflow about that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182752/central-limit-theorem-via-maximal-entropy).